# entlib 5 and structuremap

Tags: .net, structuremap, enterprise-library

I am trying to configure entlib 5 with a structuremap.

All examples are mostly based on Unity Container, can you point me to the link / example for structuremap and entlib 5 configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Somebody needs to write a StructureMap configurator first. I don't know of any, but there may be one out there. Once that exists, it should be pretty straightforward.